# regular expression for capturing multiple digits in a group

Tags: regex

Okay so I have input in the form of

```
textsem:Predicate xmi:id="1695" sofa="1" begin="67" end="71" relations="1869    1879 1889" frameSet="lead.03"
```

&&

```
textsem:Predicate xmi:id="1709" sofa="1" begin="135" end="142" relations="1842 1852" frameSet="lead.03"
```

I want to extract only the relations using regular expressions and append the values to a list.

The regular expression I'm using is:

```
(relations=)(")(\d+\s*)+(")
```

However, when I try to append group(3) to my list it is only capturing the last value in each line.  i.e. in  the example input above it is only getting 1889 and 1852 respectively and I'm not sure as to why.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ah the answer was to enclose the `+` quantifier in the group for groups 3 i.e.

```
(relations=)(")((\d+\s*)+)(")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use: `relations="((?:\d+\s*)+)"`

Comment: The regex I posted is capturing what I need it to.  Is there any benefit in using relations="((?:\d+\s*)+)" ?

Comment: You have unnecessary groups, but you just need only one group.